# Facebook recommend button auto closes

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-recommendations

When I click recommend button there's another div that will pop up wherein you can post it to your wall but it closes automatically and go back to its previous state. Does anyone know hot to fix it? Thank you so much!